# Is there any conventional way to do a per voxel shader programming?

Tags: opengl, cuda, directx, voxel

I'm finding a way to do 3d filters in directx or opengl shaders, same as the gaussian filter for images.In detail, it is to do proccessing for every voxel of a 3d texture. 
Maybe store the volume data in slices can do it, but it is not a friendly way to access the volume data and not easy to write in shaders.

sorry for my poor english, any reply will be appreciate.

p.s.:Cuda's texture memory can do this work, but my poor gpu can only run in a very low frame rate with debug model,and i don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 3D texture target in both Direct3D and OpenGL. Of course target framebuffers are still 2D. So using a compute shader, OpenCL or DirectCompute may be better suited for pure filter purposes, that don't include rendering to screen.